# is it possible to display the date as 01 Jan 2015 instead of 20150101?

Tags: android

Basically i would just like to know if one can save the date when an image is taken via camera intent to Image_01Jan2015.jpg instead of Image_20150101?

Here is my code I have for that, but would like to know if it is possible to save it like Image_01Jan2015?

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My Images");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();
    image = new File(imagesFolder.getPath(), "Image_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you try pass the required formatter in your SimpleDateFormat as follow new `SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy_HHmmss")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change [dateformat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) as

```
timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
```

to

```
timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy").format(new Date());
```

Comment: As simple as that.  Thanks!!

Comment: That was so easy... You knew `yyyy` was representing the year, right? Documentation? Anyway, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You've got to change the format-String you're passing to the SimpleDateFormat-Constructer, from

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy_HHmmss")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace:

```
timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
```

with:

```
timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy").format(new Date());
```

You can experiment with other forms by using the Android Developer API guidelines: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
```

to

```
timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy").format(new Date());
```

Please refer to the official [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)